# How to install and switch between languages (English/Japanes) in Debian

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'd like to be able to install and switch to a Japanese keyboard and back to English. Notice that this is also a question of usability. I'd like to be able to type Japanese directly, in any program, without Romaji Input mode.

At the moment, I can type Japanese in emacs, using the [Romaji Japanese input mode](http://Japanese_input_methods#Romaji_input). But if I want to type `く` for example, I have to type k-u. I'd like to be able to type it directly (that is, I type `h` for `く`.

Comment: Would you care to expand exactly which environment you are using? People wont be guessing it. Gnome, KDE, version, Debian version.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: it's Gnome 3.22, Debian 9.7,.